# Warning: Error in py_run_file_impl: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'case1'

Tags: python, r, python-import, importerror

I'm trying to run a Python script via user interface of Shiny in R. Below code is able to run it. (I'm successful in running `task1.py` via user interface of ***Shiny*** in `server.R`). But I'm getting error because of directory issue.

***Path of folders:***

```
D:\PycharmProjects\Tasks\applications\task1.py
D:\PycharmProjects\Tasks\server.R
D:\PycharmProjects\Tasks\case1\application_core.py
```

***server.R:***

```
  observeEvent(input$action,{
    py_run_file("applications/task1.py")
  })
```

***task1.py:***

```
import sys
import os  
from case1.application_core import AcousticScene
```

By running `server.R`, I'm getting error

```
Warning: Error in py_run_file_impl: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'case'
  76: <Anonymous>
```

Please don't mark this question as duplicate, I'm getting this in R not in Python. `task1.py` gives no error in Pycharm and run successfully in it. Anyone know how can I resolve this?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with your PYTHONPATH. Try this: In `task1.py` comment the third line and instead, only do `print(sys.path)`. Then execute `task1.py` once from Pycharm (the way the import worked before) and once using your R script. Post the results pls

Comment: @FlyingTeller
['D:\\PycharmProjects\\Tasks\\applications', 'D:\\PycharmProjects\\Tasks', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: There was two things I asked you to do. You only provided one output and didn't specify which one it is. Also please append this information to your question rather than posting it in comments

Comment: @FlyingTeller how can I resolve my problem?

Comment: either add `D:\PycharmProjects\Tasks` to your python path or use relative imports as running.t suggested

Comment: Error is resolved. Thanks I used:
sys.path.append("D:\PycharmProjects\Tasks")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see `baseline\case1\application_core.py` is in different directory than your working dir and `task.py`. So assuming `baseline` is not in your `PYTHONPATH` you could use [relative imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) if you want `task.py` to *see* `\baseline\case1\application_core.py` module.

```
from ...baseline.case1.application_core import AcousticScene
```

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker You only need to adjust the answer to your new path specifications

Comment: Error is resolved. Thanks. I used:
sys.path.append("D:\PycharmProjects\Tasks")